# Bootstrap collapsed navbar items misaligned

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I finally got my Bootstrap navbar working with the search and shopping cart items in the navbar-header.

Now unfortunately when I collapse the menu, the menu items move up to the top. This happens since I'm using pull-left and pull-right for my navbar-headers. However if I remove those classes, the whole thing gets wonky.

How can I fix this?

Please see the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ttcYkU1ZgUjA1ekb8pbH?p=preview

```
<nav id="bootstrapOverride" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-flex">
        <img class="hidden-xs" id="logoBig" src="content/img/logoGM.png" width="304" height="236" alt="Gute Mine logo">
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img class="visible-xs" src="content/img/logoGM.png" width="210" height="60" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
            <ul class="nav pull-left" id="menuIcons">
                <li class="visible-xs pull-left"><a ui-sref=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>
                <li class="visible-xs pull-left"><a ui-sref=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="isNavCollapsed">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref="">Neu</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="">Papier</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="">Stifte</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="">Technik</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="">Zubehör</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="">Geschenke</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-xs"><a ui-sref=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Suche</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-xs"><a ui-sref=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Warenkorb</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `navbar-header pull-left` is telling your image to float left which will make your menu move up like that.

Comment: Yea exactly :) But if I remove the pull-left the image is not in line with the other icons anymore. So what can I use instead so it all works?

Comment: If you tell your `navbar-collapse` to `clear:left` it should fix it

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it :)